# The distance between lines in a <h1> is too little: the texts overlap

Tags: html, css

I have an `<h1>` which I have styled with the following `CSS`:

```
#col2 h1 {
    text-align: left;
    padding: 2.5%;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    width: 95%;
    background-color: #444;
    border-bottom: solid 1px black;
    cursor: pointer;

    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
```

For some reason, the text appears as follows:
[image: screenshot of the <h1>]

I first guessed that this could be due to the fact I have set `margin:0;` but when I changed it to `2.5%` the distance between the lines stayed the same and a gap appeared at the top of the dark gray area.

Comment: nothing in this css would cause that. use a DOM inspector to see what other rules are applying. probably you've got a `line-height` override somewhere.

Comment: Questions concerning problems with code you've written must **describe the specific problem** — and **include valid code** to reproduce it — in the question itself. See [SSCCE.org](http://sscce.org/) for guidance.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha Well, I thought putting in a huge chunk of code would make it harder to follow through. I just have an `<h1>` tag within a `<div>` tag. Nowhere in my css have I used the property `line-height`. I did not know that it could be relevant — I am new to css — therefore I did not post the whole CSS, nor have I stated I do not have that property. Normally I post more detailed, reproducible code, but intuitively, I thought the problem was within the css of h1 only.

Comment: I'm not asking for a giant piece of code. I'm asking for a valid code that clearly reproduces the problem. Because your currently supplied one does not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Specify the `line-height`:

```
h1 {
    line-height: 1.4em; /* or whatever... */
}
```

Though in your posted CSS there's nothing to cause this problem, so I'd suggest using the browser's developer tools (<kbd>F12</kbd> in most browsers) to inspect to see where the `line-height` is coming from, or from where it's being overridden.

Incidentally the `margin` of a block-level element exists around the outer-edges of the 'box' formed by the element, it doesn't have an effect on the spacing between the lines of text contained *within* that element.

Answer (score 1):

```
line-height:10px;
```

try increasing the line height